# Printing different image for different list data

Tags: python-3.x, list, image, tkinter

so i made a list and i used tkinter for choosing a random data in list and showing that in a showinfo box. now i was just wondering if its possible to make a random image for random data.
for eg i am making a app that generates a random anime name from the list but i want to add the anime picture also is there any way i can do that ?
i haven't tried building it but here is what i have made so far.

i have no error i just want to have different picture for different names from the list chose randomly

```
  import random 
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import messagebox

anime = [
"1 Ore ga Ojousama Gakkou ni ' Shomin Sample'  Toshite Gets♥Sareta Ken",

"2 Ookami to Koushinryou II",

"3 Ookami to Koushinryou",

"4 Grisaia no Kajitsu",

"5 Nyanko Days",

"6 Suzumiya Haruhi no Shoushitsu",

"7 Ookami Kodomo no Ame to Yuki",

"8 Sankarea",

"9 Boku no Hero Academia the Movie 2: Heroes Rising",

"10 Tensei shitara Slime Datta Ken OVA",

"11 Nakitai Watashi wa Neko wo Kaburu ", 
 
"12 Tensei shitara Slime Datta Ken",

"13 Nande Koko ni Sensei ga!?", 

"14 Kotonoha no Niwa", 

"15 Chuunibyou demo Koi ga Shitai! Movie: Take On Me", 

"16 Byousoku 5 Centimeter",

"17 Summer Wars",

"18 Tenki no Ko ",

"19 Kimi no Na wa.", 

"20 Sword Art Online: Alicization – War of Underworld",

"21 Hinamatsuri",

"22 Gakuen Babysitters ",

"23 Yahari Ore no Seishun Love Comedy wa Machigatteiru. Zoku",

"24 Yahari Ore no Seishun Love Comedy wa Machigatteiru.",

"25 Hataraku Maou-sama!",
     
"26 Shokugeki no Souma: Shin no Sara",

"27 Shokugeki no Souma: San no Sara – Toutsuki Ressha-hen",

"28 Sewayaki Kitsune no Senko-san",

"29 Shokugeki no Souma: San no Sara",

"30 Shokugeki no Souma: Ni no Sara",

"31 Shokugeki no Soma ",

"32 Ao no Exorcist ",

"33 Ao no Exorcist: Kyoto Fujouou-hen",

"34 Boku dake ga Inai Machi",

"35 Kono Subarashii Sekai ni Shukufuku wo!: Kurenai Densetsu",

"36 Hyouka",

"37 Kami no Tou",

"38 Youkoso Jitsuryoku Shijou Shugi no Kyoushitsu e",

"39 Shingeki no Kyojin Season 3",

"40 Kaguya-sama wa Kokurasetai?: Tensai-tachi no Renai Zunousen 2nd Season",

"41 Shingeki no Kyojin Season 3 Part 2",

"42 Shingeki no Kyojin Season 2",

"43 Shingeki no Kyojin ",

"44 Kono Subarashii Sekai ni Shukufuku wo! 2",

"45 Seishun Buta Yarou wa Yumemiru Shoujo no Yume wo Minai",

"46 Kono Subarashii Sekai ni Shukufuku wo!",

"47 Seishun Buta Yarou wa Bunny Girl Senpai no Yume wo Minai",

"48 Sakurasou no Pet na Kanojo",

"49 Tate no Yuusha no Nariagari",

"50 IS: Infinite Stratos",

"51 Kawaikereba Hentai demo Suki ni Natte Kuremasu ka?",

"52 Enen no Shouboutai",

"53 Kaguya-sama wa Kokurasetai: Tensai-tachi no Renai Zunousen",

"54 Chuunibyou demo Koi ga Shitai! Ren",

"55 Koe no Katachi ",

"56 Dr. Stone",

"57 One Punch Man",

"58 Naruto Shippuden", 

"59 Sword Art Online II",

"60 Sword Art Online",

"61 Ansatsu Kyoushitsu 2nd season",

"62 Ansatsu Kyoushitsu",

"63 Chuunibyou demo Koi ga Shitai!",

"64 Kimetsu no Yaiba",

"65 Re:Zero kara Hajimeru Isekai Seikatsu",

"66 Nanatsu no Taizai",
 
"67 Steins;Gate 0",

"68 Steins;Gate",

"69 Nanatsu no Taizai: Imashime no Fukkatsu",

"70 Tokyo Ghoul √A",

"71 One Punch Man Season 2",

"72 Hunter x Hunter (2011)",

"73 Darling in the FranXX",

"74 Tokyo Ghoul",

"75 Boku no Hero Academia 3rd Season.",

"76 Boku no Hero Academia",

"77 Nanatsu no Taizai: Kamigami no Gekirin",

"78 Naruto",

"79 Boku no Hero Academia 4th Season",

"80 Arte",

"81 Yakusoku no Neverland",

"82 Aho Girl",

"83 Wotaku ni Koi wa Muzukashii",

"84 Kimi no Suizou wo Tabetai ",

"85 Sakasama no Patema",

"86 Grisaia no Rakuen",

"87 Kimi ni Todoke",

"88 Kimi ni Todoke 2nd Season",

"89 Sukitte Ii na yo.",

"90 Ore wo Suki nano wa Omae dake ka yo",

"91 Koi To Uso",
 
"92 Saijaku Muhai no Bahamut",

"93 7 seeds",

"94 7 Seeds 2nd Season",

"95 Kono Yo no Hate de Koi wo Utau Shoujo YU-NO",

"96 Gotoubun no Hanayome",

"97 Masamune-kun no Revenge",

"98 Tokyo Magnitude 8.0",

"99 Keppeki Danshi! Aoyama-kun Episode ",

"100  Ao Haru Ride",

"101 Kakegurui",

"102 Kakegurui××",

"103 Tokyo Ghoul:re",

"104 Tokyo Ghoul:re 2nd season",

"105 Toradora!",

"106 Sounan Desu ka?",

"107 Denpa Onna to Seishun Otoko",

"108 Zenonzard The Animation",

"109 Hanamaru Kindergarden",

"110 Tonari no Kaibutsu-kun",
 
"111 Domestic na Kanojo",

"112 Haikyuu!!",

"113 Haikyuu!! Second Season",

"114 Haikyuu!!: Karasuno Koukou vs. Shiratorizawa Gakuen Koukou",

"115 Haikyuu!!: To the Top",

"116 Sword Art Online: Alicization – War of Underworld 2nd Season",

"117 Haikyuu!!: To the Top",

"118 Yahari Ore no Seishun Love Comedy wa Machigatteiru. Kan",

"119 Kanojo, Okarishimasu",

"120 Shokugeki no Souma: Gou no Sara",

"121 Maou Gakuin no Futekigousha: Shijou Saikyou no Maou no Shiso, Tensei shite Shison-tachi no Gakkou e",

"122 UZAKI-CHAN WA ASOBITAI!",

"123 ReLIFE",

"124 ReLIFE: Kanketsu-hen",

"125 The God of High School",

"126 Inou-Battle wa Nichijou-kei no Naka de",

"127 Kyoukai no Kanata",

"128 Arifureta Shokugyou de Sekai Saikyou",

"129 ISEKAI MAOU TO SHOUKAN SHOUJO NO DOREI MAJUTSU",

"130 AKAME GA KILL!",

"131 Re:Zero kara Hajimeru Isekai Seikatsu 2nd Season",

"132 Shinchou Yuusha: Kono Yuusha ga Ore Tueee Kuse ni Shinchou Sugiru",

"133 Noragami",

"134 Noragami OVA",

"135 Noragami Aragoto",

"136 Nisekoi",

"137 Nisekoi:",

"138 Black Bullet",

"139 Devils Line",

"140 TABOO TATTOO",

"141 Hajimete no Gal ",

"142 Kuzu no Honkai",

"143 Tsurezure Children",

"144 Himouto! Umaru-chan",

"145 Boku no Kanojo ga Majimesugiru Sho-bitch na Ken",

"146 Bungou Stray Dogs",

"147 Bungou Stray Dogs Season 2",

"148 Bungou Stray Dogs 3rd Season",

"149 Lovely★Complex",

"150 Plunderer",

"151 TONIKAKU KAWAII",

"152 Enen no Shouboutai: Ni no Shou",

"153 Haikyuu!!: To the Top 2nd Season",

"154 Shigatsu wa Kimi no Uso",

"155 Kaichou wa Maid-sama",

"156 Karakai Jouzu no Takagi-san",

"157 Karakai Jouzu no Takagi-san 2"]

top = Tk()
top.geometry("200x100")

def fun():
    
    messagebox.showinfo("Anime", random.choice(anime))

can = Canvas(top, height = 100, width = 100)
can.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
b1 = Button(can,text = "Generate",command = fun,activeforeground = "black",activebackground = "yellow",pady=10)
b1.pack(side = TOP)

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you want to display images on canvas or labels? should the image be random or be corresponding to the anime title?

Comment: If you have another list of image filenames, you can use `random.choice()` to select a image file randomly from the list.

Comment: @JacksonPro yes i want the image to be corresponding to the anime title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want the image to be corresponding to the anime titles I suggest you use a dictionary instead of a list. Also, use `Toplevel` widget to display the output.

So here is an example code:

```
import random 
from tkinter import*
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

absolute_path = r'C:\Users\ ' # your absolute path goes here(Note: Don't remove the extra space in the end) 

anime = {
"1 Ore ga Ojousama Gakkou ni ' Shomin Sample'  Toshite Gets♥Sareta Ken": 'Akira.png', # anime image name

"2 Ookami to Koushinryou II": 'Alex.jpg', # anime image name
}

root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x100")

def fun():

    top = Toplevel(root)
    top.title('Anime')

    random_choice = random.choice(list(anime.keys())) #choosing random from dictionary keys
    
    label = Label(top, text=random_choice)
    label.pack()

    top.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(absolute_path.strip()+anime[random_choice]))
    
    image_label = Label(top, image=top.img)
    image_label.pack()

can = Canvas(root, height = 100, width = 100)
can.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

b1 = Button(can,text = "Generate",command = fun,activeforeground = "black",activebackground = "yellow",pady=10)
b1.pack(side = TOP)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: so the absolute path allows the code to find the image from anywhere in pc? r8 and is there anything i need to change in the code or can i just paste it ?

Comment: i copy pasted the code and i put the absolute path of the folder where i  stored the image and for the list i added naruto and naruto,jpeg image and then when i run it i get this error 
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL' `
and then when i tried pip installing it said pil could not be found but when i use pillow it says requirement already satisfied

Comment: @Fox_Glove21 No you don't need to change anything from the code. Yes, the absolute path allows you to access images from any folder on your PC. Can you try running it from cmd or terminal and tell me what error you get?